# How to modify Albedo of a shader through code in Lightweight Render Pipeline Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I was wondering if it were possible to run something like this function (from a standard surface shader) in a lightweight render pipeline shader as such:

```
 void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {
     // Albedo comes from a texture tinted by color
     fixed4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
     o.Albedo = c.rgb;
     // Metallic and smoothness come from slider variables
     o.Metallic = _Metallic;
     o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
     o.Alpha = c.a;
  }
```

All I am interested in is modifying the `Albedo` of what would be the Lightweight Render Pipeline equivalent of the `SurfaceOutputStandard`. Would doing something like this through custom programming a shader in Unity be possible? If so, how?

If I am being too vague, please don't hesitate to ask for more information. :)

Comment: You can download and use the Shader graph, and expose a texture variable that you can then get via code. It's on the package manager, plenty of youtube tutorials available

Comment: @Jichael Sorry if I don't quite understand what you're saying, but do you mean adding some sort of property that then changes the Albedo of the actual material?